# Is it possible to make the text look exactly the same on all devices?

Tags: css

Here, I put text inside the div created as follows.

```
<div>There are Sentences that start like this, go on like this, and end like this</div>
```

result
[image]

If you look at this text, 'and' and 'end' have line breaks.
Is it possible via css to make the line break appear as if it happened between 'and' and 'end' on any device without disabling the viewport? From any device, there should be a line break between 'and' and 'end', just like the text in the image. I want this text to look the same on mobile, desktop, and tablet.

If more text is added here, I'm thinking that the character position, punctuation mark position, and line break position will look the same on all devices.

Comment: Why not just a styled `<br />`?

Comment: I'm thinking of a case where the line is automatically wrapped because of a long sentence, rather than manually wrapping the line like the `<br>` tag.

Comment: Well, I do remember a special unicode character to denote special breaks like these, but again, not all devices render or respect this, and also I don't know where I found it. One of those things that you see and lingers in the back of your mind for a while.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Are you also wanting the text to be justified both right and left?

Comment: I don't think you can rely on pure CSS for this, you will have to build the line breaks you want into the actual text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can ever guarantee it without setting specific widths.

However, there is an element `<wbr>` which is used to denote a position where a line break should (preferably) occur.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr

Comment: Note that even when setting specific widths, some browsers can render the same font slightly differently. This is an issue I've come across in previous works.

Comment: It seems almost impossible to make the text fit the same as the div size changes on all devices. Thanks.